# Big differences in join time on similar tables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have two tables described below. I generally join this tables (inner join) with smaller another tables.  However, upon checking the execution time, Table 2 takes approximately 9 minutes, whereas Table 1 takes about 2 hours. Additionally, I noticed that there is no ColumnarToRow node and 2nd WholeStageCodegen node in the execution summary for Table 1 joins. I use broadcast join both.

**Table 1:**
Size 8TB
Column count 151

**Table 2:**
Size 5.5TB
Column count 90

Join columns are same and both table has liquid clustered on same column. Both are optimized.

**Join with Table1 execution summary**

```
Completed in 6292595ms
Node(row)
*WholeStageCodegen(1)
-*(5):ColumnarToRow(253,461)
-*(6):Filter(253,461)
(1):Scan parquet **table1** (10,305,644,145)
(2):Filter(9,622,877,502)
(3):Project
(4):Scan parquet **smaller_table** (253,461)
(7):Exchange
(9):BroadcastHashJoin(28,206,425)
(10):Project
(11):WriteFiles
(12):ExecuteWriteIntoDeltaCommand
(13):ResultQueryStage
(23):AdaptiveSparkPlan
```

**Join with Table2 execution summary**

```
Completed in 567963 ms
Node (row)
*WholeStageCodegen(1)
-*(6):ColumnarToRow (253,461)
-*(7):Filter (253,461)
*WholeStageCodegen(2)
-*(2):ColumnarToRow (19,364,719,597)
-*(3):Filter (17,548,253,303)
-*(4):Project
-*(10):BroadcastHashJoin (65,712,508)
-*(11):Project
(1):Scan parquet **table2** (19,364,719,597)
(5):Scan parquet **smaller_table**  (253,461)
(8):Exchange
(12):WriteFiles
(13):ExecuteWriteIntoDeltaCommand
(14):ResultQueryStage
(24):AdaptiveSparkPlan
```

Thanks

Comment: You should try to use explicit broadcast as here `result_df = large_df.join(broadcast(small_df), "join_key", "inner")` Don't rely on the autobroadcast join threshold. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41046320/3238085  You can determine size of your smaller table using this 
```import org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator

logInfo(SizeEstimator.estimate(yourlargeorsmalldataframehere))
```

Comment: more discussion here : https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/what-is-the-quot-columnar-to-row-quot-node-in-this-simple/td-p/48888

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62181813/3238085  : Just to update my previous comment on how to calculate size estimates. You can simply use this `df.explain(mode='cost')`  This gives you `Statistics(sizeInBytes=123.0 B, rowCount=4)`

Comment: Thanks for comment. I use explicit broadcast as like in your comment. It looks spark can perform broadcast join for both join.  I think the problem not related with broadcast join. Additionally, WholeStageCodegen also not available in Table1 join.

Comment: Broadcast join is a hint which may not be respected in the final plan. Can you check the final physical plan and see if broadcast hashjoin is happening? You can also try to see with `mode=cost ` and see if you can get more information.

Comment: I get execution summaries from spark UI completed job details. They are final plan.

Comment: Ok. next I would test if the same plans are generated by restricting the table to a much smaller size which will finish faster. e.g  ,`table(1/2).limit(100)` . This will rule out whether the different plans are due to sizes.

Comment: Now I have tried but plan is same. Just, limit nodes are added.

Comment: Additionally I increase cluster size (x2 mem and cpu) the plan still is same.

Comment: Are you doing exactly the same thing with both tables or is there some fundamental difference? Are the limits taking effect? i.e. `table1 = table1.limit(100)` just to make sure. Otherwise without knowing the exact query it is difficult to diagnose

Comment: Is your smaller table different in both cases ? Did you try printing out `explain with mode=cost` to ascertain the sizes?

Comment: No smaller table always same.  I select only first 30 columns from big table, now spark can trigger WholeStageCodegen and ColumnarToRow optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find it in the documentation or other resources, but it seems Spark considers the column count to trigger ColumnarToRow and WholeStageCodegen optimizations. When I select only ~90 columns in Table 1, it runs as fast as Table 2. Thanks for comments.